# Is Nick Fury now depicted as being Black & Bald outside the movie franchise?

Tags: comics, iron-man, marvel, nick-fury

In [Iron Man: Rise of the Technovores](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2654124/), an anime released recently, Nick Fury appears to look and talk like Samuel L. Jackson. I'm curious to know if comics, cartoons, etc. have all made a similar switch since the release of [Iron Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/) in 2008.

Comment: See also this for a similar, slightly wider question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21635/do-comic-characters-sometimes-get-drawn-like-the-actor-playing-them

Comment: Also related, and specifically about Nick Fury: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/how-true-to-character-is-the-movie-portrayal-of-nick-fury

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nick Fury portrayed as black in Marvel's Ultimate universe, where he was seen as early as 2001. You can find the information and appearances [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Nick_Fury). The Wikipedia entry even notes

> Nick Fury was redesigned to look like actor Samuel L. Jackson with his permission, who went on to portray Fury in several Marvel movies.

So Nick Fury as an African-American predates the first *Iron Man* movie by around 7 years.

However, the Nick Fury outside of the Ultimate universe and the movies is [still generally depicted as white](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Fury#Fictional_character_biography). This is the Marvel universe that has been going for around 50 years and sees Fury as a WWII vet. Ironically, in the universe where Fury is white, it has been revealed that he has a black son named [Marcus Johnson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_Johnson_%28comics%29) that also looks like Sam Jackson.

This means that you'll see Nick Fury as either white or black depending on what universe you're looking at. I would also expect that as a branding tool you'll see more spinoffs created in which Fury looks like Samuel L. Jackson. In order to sell consumers the comics, Marvel will probably start drawing characters closer to how they're depicted in the movies.

Comment: They sort of did that with the X-Men for a few years, but they've shifted back into their pre-movie depictions.

Comment: Note that Fury senior has been missing and presumed dead since the *Original Sin* event in 2014, and that son Marcus has been going by the name Nick Fury, Jr. There was a *Nick Fury* comic in 2015-2016, and it was about Jr. Also, they don't generally mention the "Junior" part, just "Nick Fury".

Comment: It's now famously known that Jackson gave Marvel permission to use his face as a model for Nick Fury so he'd be the logical choice to play Fury if the character appeared in film. There's a scene in an early issue of *The Ultimates* referencing this where the characters are discussing who would play them if Hollywood ever made a film about their adventures, and Fury smugly informed them that of course he'd be played by Samuel L. Jackson.